# Problemas com join laravel ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm

Olá,

Estou tentando criar uma query avançada, mas estou tendo alguns problemas segue o código para análise!

```
Anuncio::join('users', function ($users) use ($request){
        $users->on('users.id' , '=', 'a.user');
    })->join('enderecos', function ($enderecos) use ($request){
        $enderecos->on('enderecos.id', '=', 'users.endereco');
    })->where('enderecos.uf_id', '=', $request['uf_id'])->get();
```

A query acima funciona perfeitamente, mas quando tento adaptar ela a um outro grupo de filtros ela não funciona e da erro!

Segue o outro grupo de filtros:

```
$anuncios = Anuncio::where(function($query) use ($request)
    {
        if(isset($request['uf_id'])){
            $query->join('users', function ($users) use ($request){
                $users->on('users.id' , '=', 'a.user');
            })->join('enderecos', function ($enderecos) use ($request){
                $enderecos->on('enderecos.id', '=', 'users.endereco');
            })->where('enderecos.uf_id', '=', $request['uf_id']);
        }
        if(isset($request['modelo'])){
            $query->where('modelo', $request['modelo']);
        }
        if(isset($request['marca']))
            $query->where('marca', $request['marca']);
    })->with('anuncio_dados')->with('adicionais')
        ->with('anuncio_imagens')->with('versaos')
        ->with('marcas')->with('modelos')->paginate(10);
```

Quando tento inserir ele nesta query, o filtro de uf_id não funciona. Alguém sabe me dizer o por que?

Comment: Primeira coisa os `joins` podem ser simplificados já visto que você não usa $request nem $users ( e outros) dentro pode ser somente a passagem de valores. Outro ponto: `quando tento inserir ele nesta query o filtro de uf_id não funciona. alguem sabe me dizer o por que?` porque, o erro aparece o que?

Comment: o erro que da é esse message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'enderecos.uf_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `anuncios` as `a` where (`enderecos`.`uf_id` = 15))"

Comment: Existe a coluna `uf_id` dentro de enderecos?

Comment: sim, e como mencionei no post o que me deixou sem saber o que fazer, é que na primeira query o retorno é valido!

Comment: Achei o problema, você não pode fazer where com `join` ... você precisa fazer tudo separado, utilizando sempre a última versão do builder coletada!

Comment: Gratidão pela sua ajuda, mas como seria isso? fiquei com duvida de como fazer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o código abaixo resolve, a observação é que dentro de `where` não pode fazer um `join` faça separado utilizando sempre a última versão da instância do `builder` fazendo as criticas e passando o novo valor para a mesma variável, exemplo:

```
$builderAnuncions = Anuncio::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'anuncios.user')
                        ->join('enderecos', 'enderecos.id','=','users.endereco');

if(isset($request['uf_id']))
{
    $builderAnuncions = $builderAnuncions->where('enderecos.uf_id', '=', $request['uf_id']);
}
if(isset($request['modelo']))
{
    $builderAnuncions = $builderAnuncions->where('modelo', $request['modelo']);
}
if(isset($request['marca']))
{
    $builderAnuncions = $builderAnuncions->where('marca', $request['marca']);
}    

$builderAnuncions
    ->with('anuncio_dados')
    ->with('adicionais')
    ->with('anuncio_imagens')->with('versaos')
    ->with('marcas')
    ->with('modelos')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, você está montando a query de forma incorreta.
Tente seguindo o exemplo abaixo onde eu seleciono anúncios com nome da marca começando com a letra F e incluindo a marca do veículo no resultado.

```
$query = Anuncio::join('marcas', 'marcas.id', '=', 'anuncio.marca_id')->where('marcas.nome', 'like', 'F%')->select(['anuncios.*', 'marcas.nome']);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Junior, consegui resolver com o exemplo acima do Virgilio Novic!